# QueryDSL: Entity Manager parameter in JPAUpdateClause

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

Sorry for novice question. I am totally new in QueryDSL.
I am trying to update a record using `JPAUpdateClause` but i do not know what should i set for the first parameter `EntityManager`.
I am using `java spring`
Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class PurchaseOrder {

   @id
   @GeneratedValue
   Long id;


   String Status;
}
```

Then i used jpa to have this entity in a database:

```
@Repository
public interface PurchaseOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<PurchaseOrder, Long>,
QueryDslPredicateExecutor<PurchaseOrder>{}
```

And at the end i am trying to update a record using QueryDSL

```
static QPurchaseOrder purchaseOrder= QPurchaseOrder.purchaseOrder;
    static QPurchaseOrder purchaseOrder= QPurchaseOrder.purchaseOrder;
            new JPAUpdateClause(null, purchaseOrder).where(purchaseOrder.id.eq(id)))
            .set(purchaseOrder.status, "REJECTED")
            .execute();
```

I just set it as null, but it does not work.
I am sure I have added the dependencies in my pom.xml.
Right now it is complaining about

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

I have seen [this](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.2/reference/html/ch02.html), but it does not clarify what is the session?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to inject EntityManager like this ? It should work.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

...
new JPAUpdateClause(entityManager, purchaseOrder).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inject end use EntityManager like this:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;



private void yourUpdateMethod(){

QPurchaseOrder entity = QPurchaseOrder.purchaseOrder;
JPAUpdateClause update = new JPAQueryFactory(this.em).update(entity);

update.where(purchaseOrder.id.eq(id)))
    .set(purchaseOrder.status, "REJECTED")
    .execute();

}
```